# fb-send-to-messenger data-ref cannot pass url value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using **gem facebook-messenger**

**Send to Facebook**

When the human clicks the [Send to Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin) button embedded on a website, you will receive an optin event.

```
Bot.on :optin do |optin|
  optin.sender    # => { 'id' => '1008372609250235' }
  optin.recipient # => { 'id' => '2015573629214912' }
  optin.sent_at   # => 2016-04-22 21:30:36 +0200
  optin.ref       # => 'CONTACT_SKYNET'

  optin.reply(text: 'Ah, human!')
end


<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
  messenger_app_id="<APP_ID>" 
  page_id="PAGE_ID" 
  data-ref="<PASS_THROUGH_PARAM>" 
  color="<blue | white>" 
  size="<standard | large | xlarge>">
</div>
```

**WHEN** I tried to simple string to `data-ref`, it works.
**BUT** putting a `url` (http://asdasda/asdas/sad?/asd..) **DOESN'T WORKED**

Comment: I'd bet you need to urlencode the URL.

Comment: I think there is an error in the docs. : is not actually supported in the string.

Comment: I tried to used CGI.escape(url) but my send-to-messenger button in view does not show up, seems still data-ref="don't accept url value"

Comment: https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger/issues/203

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `data-ref` does not accept special character (e.g. !@#$%^&*()|...,

thus **encoding and decoding url** will not work.
Since e.g encoded/decoded url contains special characters like **%**.

For now, just to make my function work, what I did is make a helper method that replaces special chars.

```
def parse_product_url(url)
  url.gsub('?', 'QMARK').gsub('&', 'AND').gsub('//', '')
end
```

And do that **in-reverse** in Bot..reply argument.